# Linearise data in R (partially reversing XTABS)

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to convert list of obiects with several its features into a dataframe of obiectname, feature and value. I believe such an operation is called linearising, however I cannot find an elegant function to obtain this.

My input data looks like this:

```
 INV  SUM Part1 Part2
   A   10    10     5
   B   10     8     8
   C   12    12     4
```

and I expect to get this:

```
INV Amt  Kind
  A  10   SUM
  A  10 Part1
  A   5 Part2
  B  10   SUM
  B   8 Part1
  B   8 Part2
  C  12   SUM
  C  12 Part1
  C   4 Part2
```

This looks like the reversed XTABS() function result.

Sophisticated code utilising FOR loop works fine but requires update every time input data structure changes (i.e. additional feature column is added).

I have a hope that there is a simple function. Please indicate such a function or a manner other than FOR loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
DF = structure(list(INV = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    SUM = c(10L, 10L, 12L), Part1 = c(10L, 8L, 12L), Part2 = c(5L, 
    8L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Use tidyr and dplyr libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% pivot_longer(-INV)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  INV   name  value
  <fct> <chr> <int>
1 A     SUM      10
2 A     Part1    10
3 A     Part2     5
4 B     SUM      10
5 B     Part1     8
6 B     Part2     8
7 C     SUM      12
8 C     Part1    12
9 C     Part2     4
```